# $x$ being a real number, calculate the number of acute triangles formed with sides of $5$, $x+1$,and $x$.

Tags: geometry

Can there be infinite amount of acute triangles, since $x$ can be any real number?

If $x$ was any integer, the problem will be much  easier, since I can just calculate $x$ assuming that it is a right triangle. And list out all the possible values given the limits.

Comment: Why can you assume that it's a right triangle if $x$ is an integer?

Comment: To know the max value each variable can be

Comment: If you can show that there are at least two different integer solutions, then you have succeeded in proving that there are infinite number of acute triangles, since any solution between the two integer solutions must also be valid.

Answer (score 3):

**Case 1** ($x>4$): The side $x+1$ is the longest. Since the triangle must be acute:
$$(x+1)^2<x^2+5^2$$
which yields
$$x<12$$

**Case 2** ($x\le4$): The side $5$ is the longest. Now,
$$5^2<x^2+(x+1)^2$$
which reduces to
$$x^2+x-12>0$$
or
$$(x+4)(x-3)>0$$
which is satisfied only if $x>3$.

Thus,
$$3<x<12$$

Comment: @Doeser If $x$ can be any real in that interval, of course.

Comment: I see that you didn't know the property of acute triangles that I have used. It is an easy cosequence of the law of the cosine.

Comment: For the first case, 5 can also be the largest if the triangle is isosceles?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The triangle inequality states that if $a_1$, $a_2$ and $a_3$ are sides of a triangle then $$a_1+a_2>a_3$$

Look at this theorem and others concerning sides of triangles.

Comment: I know this already

Comment: How many other theorems are there?

Comment: @Doeser the converse of the theorem I just named states that a triangle cannot be constructed from three line segments if any of them is longer than the sum of the other two. That should help you.

Comment: For an acute triangle, you also have $a_1^2+a_2^2>a_3^2$.

Comment: @KSmarts that is cool I didn't know that.

Comment: @Joao If follows from the cosine rule...